# Changing the GPU clock rate on a linux like system (Nvidia Jetson TX1)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpu, clock

I have a Nvidia Jetson tx1 board and want to change the gpu rate by writing in the following file:

```
sudo echo 691200000 > /sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/rate
sudo echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/state
```

However I get greeted with a

> Permission denied

I know the commands from the following script https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-scripts/blob/master/jetson_max_l4t.sh which was proposed by an nvidia-employee. However I do not want to max out the gpu clock frequency, I want to set it to a specific setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the redirection happens in your non-root user environment, not under `sudo`.

Try this instead:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 691200000 > /sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/rate'
```

and similarly for the second setting.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me hint about the difference between writing sudo (which I thought would imply that I am a root user) to using sudo bash -c ?

Comment: @Kev1n91: The hint was already in the answer: In your question you redirect the output of a command to that file; the command happens to be sudo but it's your own user doing the redirection. The version in the answer starts bash with `sudo` rights, so everything inside the given command string has `sudo` rights, including the redirection.