# permision denied when change gpu clock rate in TX1

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia

I have a Nvidia TX1 development kit which I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 using JetPack-L4T-3.1-linux-x64.run (in full installation mode) on it. 
The installation procedure are based on the following link:
" http://docs.nvidia.com/jetpack-l4t/2_1/content/developertools/mobile/jetpack/jetpack_l4t/2.0/jetpack_l4t_install.htm "

I wanted to test its GPU performance for our application but since its clock is set to the minimum value which is 76800000 HZ. I can't get enough performance out of it.
I've read in this link: " [Changing the GPU clock rate on a linux like system (Nvidia Jetson TX1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146835/changing-the-gpu-clock-rate-on-a-linux-like-system-nvidia-jetson-tx1) " to change the value of GPU clock rate, but permission denied happens for my Linux! Is there any hope for changing the clock speed of the GPU on this board ?

It is worth mentioning that instead of having this path for changing clock rate 
/sys/kernel/debug/clock/override.gbus/rate
I have this path:
/sys/kernel/debug/clk/override.gbus/clk_rate

So you can see I don't have any clock folder or rate file ! I can see different options for GPU clock rate in this file: /sys/kernel/debug/clk/gbus/clk_possible_rates

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Unix & Linux SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is that you should not look in that path for changing the clock.

just run the following bash file with sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) 2015-2017, NVIDIA CORPORATION. All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#  * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#  * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#  * Neither the name of NVIDIA CORPORATION nor the names of its
#    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
#    from this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS ``AS IS'' AND ANY
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
# PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
# CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
# EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
# PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
# PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY
# OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

CONF_FILE=${HOME}/l4t_dfs.conf
RED='\e[0;31m'
GREEN='\e[0;32m'
BLUE='\e[0;34m'
BRED='\e[1;31m'
BGREEN='\e[1;32m'
BBLUE='\e[1;34m'
NC='\e[0m' # No Color

usage()
{
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
        echo -e ${RED}"$1"${NC}
    fi

        cat >& 2 <<EOF
Maximize jetson performance by setting static max frequency to CPU, GPU and EMC clocks.
Usage:
jetson_clocks.sh [options]
  options,
  --show             display current settings
  --store [file]     store current settings to a file (default: \${HOME}/l4t_dfs.conf)
  --restore [file]   restore saved settings from a file (default: \${HOME}/l4t_dfs.conf)
  run jetson_clocks.sh without any option to set static max frequency to CPU, GPU and EMC clocks.
EOF

    exit 0
}

restore()
{
    for conf in `cat "${CONF_FILE}"`; do
        file=`echo $conf | cut -f1 -d :`
        data=`echo $conf | cut -f2 -d :`
        case "${file}" in
            /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online |\
            /sys/kernel/debug/clk/override*/state)
                if [ `cat $file` -ne $data ]; then
                    echo "${data}" > "${file}"
                fi
                ;;
            /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq |\
            /sys/kernel/debug/tegra_cpufreq/*_CLUSTER/cc3/enable)
                echo "${data}" > "${file}" 2>/dev/null
                ;;
            *)
                echo "${data}" > "${file}"
                ret=$?
                if [ ${ret} -ne 0 ]; then
                    echo "Error: Failed to restore $file"
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

store()
{
    for file in $@; do
        if [ -e "${file}" ]; then
            echo "${file}:`cat ${file}`" >> "${CONF_FILE}"
        fi
    done
}

do_fan()
{
    # Jetson-TK1 CPU fan is always ON.
    if [ "${machine}" = "jetson-tk1" ] ; then
            return
    fi

    if [ ! -w /sys/kernel/debug/tegra_fan/target_pwm ]; then
        echo "Can't access Fan!"
        return
    fi

    case "${ACTION}" in
        show)
            echo "Fan: speed=`cat /sys/kernel/debug/tegra_fan/target_pwm`"
            ;;
        store)
            store "/sys/kernel/debug/tegra_fan/target_pwm"
            ;;
        *)
            FAN_SPEED=255
            echo "${FAN_SPEED}" > /sys/kernel/debug/tegra_fan/target_pwm
            ;;
    esac
}

do_clusterswitch()
{
    case "${ACTION}" in
        show)
            if [ -d "/sys/kernel/cluster" ]; then
                ACTIVE_CLUSTER=`cat /sys/kernel/cluster/active`
                echo "CPU Cluster Switching: Active Cluster ${ACTIVE_CLUSTER}"
            else
                echo "CPU Cluster Switching: Disabled"
            fi
            ;;
        store)
            if [ -d "/sys/kernel/cluster" ]; then
                store "/sys/kernel/cluster/immediate"
                store "/sys/kernel/cluster/force"
                store "/sys/kernel/cluster/active"
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            if [ -d "/sys/kernel/cluster" ]; then
                echo 1 > /sys/kernel/cluster/immediate
                echo 0 > /sys/kernel/cluster/force
                echo G > /sys/kernel/cluster/active
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}

do_hotplug()
{
    case "${ACTION}" in
        show)
            echo "Online CPUs: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online`"
            ;;
        store)
            for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]/online; do
                store "${file}"
            done
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "${SOCFAMILY}" != "tegra186" ]; then
                for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online; do
                    if [ `cat $file` -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo 1 > "${file}"
                    fi
                done
            fi
    esac
}

do_cpu()
{
    FREQ_GOVERNOR="cpufreq/scaling_governor"
    CPU_MIN_FREQ="cpufreq/scaling_min_freq"
    CPU_MAX_FREQ="cpufreq/scaling_max_freq"
    CPU_CUR_FREQ="cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"
    CPU_SET_SPEED="cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"
    INTERACTIVE_SETTINGS="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/interactive"
    SCHEDUTIL_SETTINGS="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/schedutil"

    case "${ACTION}" in
        show)
            for folder in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]; do
                CPU=`basename ${folder}`
                if [ -e "${folder}/${FREQ_GOVERNOR}" ]; then
                    echo "$CPU: Gonvernor=`cat ${folder}/${FREQ_GOVERNOR}`" \
                        "MinFreq=`cat ${folder}/${CPU_MIN_FREQ}`" \
                        "MaxFreq=`cat ${folder}/${CPU_MAX_FREQ}`" \
                        "CurrentFreq=`cat ${folder}/${CPU_CUR_FREQ}`"
                fi
            done
            ;;
        store)
            store "/sys/module/qos/parameters/enable"

            for file in \
                /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq; do
                store "${file}"
            done

            if [ "${SOCFAMILY}" = "tegra186" ]; then
                store "/sys/kernel/debug/tegra_cpufreq/M_CLUSTER/cc3/enable"
                store "/sys/kernel/debug/tegra_cpufreq/B_CLUSTER/cc3/enable"
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            echo 0 > /sys/module/qos/parameters/enable

            if [ "${SOCFAMILY}" = "tegra186" ]; then
                echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tegra_cpufreq/M_CLUSTER/cc3/enable 2>/dev/null
                echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tegra_cpufreq/B_CLUSTER/cc3/enable 2>/dev/null
            fi

            for folder in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]; do
                cat "${folder}/${CPU_MAX_FREQ}" > "${folder}/${CPU_MIN_FREQ}" 2>/dev/null
            done
            ;;
    esac
}

do_gpu()
{
    case "${SOCFAMILY}" in
        tegra186)
            GPU_MIN_FREQ="/sys/devices/17000000.gp10b/devfreq/17000000.gp10b/min_freq"
            GPU_MAX_FREQ="/sys/devices/17000000.gp10b/devfreq/17000000.gp10b/max_freq"
            GPU_CUR_FREQ="/sys/devices/17000000.gp10b/devfreq/17000000.gp10b/cur_freq"
            GPU_RAIL_GATE="/sys/devices/17000000.gp10b/railgate_enable"
            ;;
        tegra210)
            GPU_MIN_FREQ="/sys/devices/57000000.gpu/devfreq/57000000.gpu/min_freq"
            GPU_MAX_FREQ="/sys/devices/57000000.gpu/devfreq/57000000.gpu/max_freq"
            GPU_CUR_FREQ="/sys/devices/57000000.gpu/devfreq/57000000.gpu/cur_freq"
            GPU_RAIL_GATE="/sys/devices/57000000.gpu/railgate_enable"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error! unsupported SOC ${SOCFAMILY}"
            exit 1;
            ;;
    esac

    case "${ACTION}" in
        show)
            echo "GPU MinFreq=`cat ${GPU_MIN_FREQ}`" \
                "MaxFreq=`cat ${GPU_MAX_FREQ}`" \
                "CurrentFreq=`cat ${GPU_CUR_FREQ}`"
            ;;
        store)
            store "${GPU_MIN_FREQ}"
            store "${GPU_RAIL_GATE}"
            ;;
        *)
            echo 0 > "${GPU_RAIL_GATE}"
            cat "${GPU_MAX_FREQ}" > "${GPU_MIN_FREQ}"
            ret=$?
            if [ ${ret} -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "Error: Failed to max GPU frequency!"
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}

do_emc()
{
    case "${SOCFAMILY}" in
        tegra186)
            EMC_ISO_CAP="/sys/kernel/nvpmodel_emc_cap/emc_iso_cap"
            EMC_MIN_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/bpmp/debug/clk/emc/min_rate"
            EMC_MAX_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/bpmp/debug/clk/emc/max_rate"
            EMC_CUR_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/clk/emc/clk_rate"
            EMC_UPDATE_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/bpmp/debug/clk/emc/rate"
            EMC_FREQ_OVERRIDE="/sys/kernel/debug/bpmp/debug/clk/emc/mrq_rate_locked"
            ;;
        tegra210)
            EMC_MIN_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/tegra_bwmgr/emc_min_rate"
            EMC_MAX_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/tegra_bwmgr/emc_max_rate"
            EMC_CUR_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/clk/override.emc/clk_rate"
            EMC_UPDATE_FREQ="/sys/kernel/debug/clk/override.emc/clk_update_rate"
            EMC_FREQ_OVERRIDE="/sys/kernel/debug/clk/override.emc/clk_state"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error! unsupported SOC ${SOCFAMILY}"
            exit 1;
            ;;

    esac
    case "${ACTION}" in
        show)
            echo "EMC MinFreq=`cat ${EMC_MIN_FREQ}`" \
                "MaxFreq=`cat ${EMC_MAX_FREQ}`" \
                "CurrentFreq=`cat ${EMC_CUR_FREQ}`" \
                "FreqOverride=`cat ${EMC_FREQ_OVERRIDE}`"
            ;;
        store)
            store "${EMC_FREQ_OVERRIDE}"
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "${SOCFAMILY}" = "tegra186" ]; then
                emc_cap=`cat "${EMC_ISO_CAP}"`
                if [ "$emc_cap" -eq 0 ]; then
                    cat "${EMC_MAX_FREQ}" > "${EMC_UPDATE_FREQ}"
                else
                    echo "$emc_cap" >  "${EMC_UPDATE_FREQ}"
                fi
            else
                cat "${EMC_MAX_FREQ}" > "${EMC_UPDATE_FREQ}"
            fi

            echo 1 > "${EMC_FREQ_OVERRIDE}"
            ;;
    esac
}

main ()
{
    while [ -n "$1" ]; do
        case "$1" in
            --show)
                echo "SOC family:${SOCFAMILY}  Machine:${machine}"
                ACTION=show
                ;;
            --store)
                [ -n "$2" ] && CONF_FILE=$2
                ACTION=store
                shift 1
                ;;
            --restore)
                [ -n "$2" ] && CONF_FILE=$2
                ACTION=restore
                shift 1
                ;;
            -h|--help)
                usage
                exit 0
                ;;
            *)
                usage "Unknown option: $1"
                exit 1
                ;;
        esac
        shift 1
    done

    [ `whoami` != root ] && \
        echo Error: Run this script\($0\) as a root user && exit 1

    case $ACTION in
        store)
            if [ -e "${CONF_FILE}" ]; then
                echo "File $CONF_FILE already exists. Can I overwrite it? Y/N:"
                read answer
                case $answer in
                    y|Y)
                        rm -f $CONF_FILE
                        ;;
                    *)
                        echo "Error: file $CONF_FILE already exists!"
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                esac
            fi
            ;;
        restore)
            if [ ! -e "${CONF_FILE}" ]; then
                echo "Error: $CONF_FILE file not found !"
                exit 1
            fi
            restore
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac

    do_hotplug
    do_clusterswitch
    do_cpu
    do_gpu
    do_emc
#   do_fan
}


if [ -e "/sys/devices/soc0/family" ]; then
    SOCFAMILY="`cat /sys/devices/soc0/family`"
    if [ -e "/sys/devices/soc0/machine" ]; then
        machine=`cat /sys/devices/soc0/machine`
    fi
elif [ -e "/proc/device-tree/compatible" ]; then
    grep "nvidia,tegra210" /proc/device-tree/compatible &>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        SOCFAMILY="tegra210"
    else
        grep "nvidia,tegra186" /proc/device-tree/compatible &>/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            SOCFAMILY="tegra186"
        fi
    fi

    if [ -e "/proc/device-tree/model" ]; then
        machine="`cat /proc/device-tree/model`"
    fi
fi

main $@
exit 0
```